# Manually adding custom options to existing products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm trying to add some custom options to already existing products in Magento. Seems to work fine, I added the needed rows in the following tables:

```
catalog_product_option
catalog_product_option_title
catalog_product_option_type_value
catalog_product_option_type_price
catalog_product_option_type_title
```

I also updated `has_options` and `required_options` for the right product, in the following tables:

```
catalog_product_entity
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_flat_2
catalog_product_flat_3
```

When I open the product, the options doesn't show, actually, it shows less. The button to order it disappears. When I open the *edit* page, it does show the options. After saving, it appears on the front-end too.

What am I missing?

**Update:**
After manually going through literally every query that was executed after a save action, I discovered what I was missing. When a product has options, it has to display them in a different *template* (or whatever it's called in Magento). To do this, you'll have to change the value for the attribute `options_container`.

So, there's a really easy fix for that. Just look up the `attribute_id` in the table `eav_attribute`. Then just run the following query for each product:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET `value` = 'container1' WHERE `attribute_id` = 836 AND `entity_id` = $productId;
```

That'll do the trick! :)

Comment: Do post the answer to this if you find out, also if you find any workarounds, such as opening and saving the product in code/api.

Comment: Solved, updated my question with the solution. A pretty easy one!

Comment: Thank you muchly and well done! (saved as favourite question...)

Comment: GuidoH, if you solved your problem, create an answer for the problem that contains the solution and then accept that as the right answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. That will signify that the question has been answered properly to future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manually going through literally every query that was executed after a save action, I discovered what I was missing. When a product has options, it has to display them in a different *template* (or whatever it's called in Magento). To do this, you'll have to change the value for the attribute `options_container`.

So, there's a really easy fix for that. Just look up the `attribute_id` in the table `eav_attribute`. Then just run the following query for each product:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET `value` = 'container1' WHERE `attribute_id` = 836 AND `entity_id` = $productId;
```

That'll do the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be accessing the database directly for any reason. This undermines the power and resourcefulness of using an EAV system.

1. Extend Mage.php if outside of magento (disregard if not)
2. Make a collection of whatever entities you want to manipulate
3. Use said collection to write/read data
4. Save yourself headaches down the road!

Comment: Gotta say.. It was the first time I've worked with Magento, for just a couple of days. Haven't touched it ever since, didn't miss it at all. But thanks for the addition. :)